# lighttpd configuration - does lighttpd authenticate with an address, e.g. subjectAltNames=IP:192.168.1.20?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lighttpd, subject-alternative-name

The following is a test setting to check if *lighttpd* will autheticate based on an IP address when it is included in certificate *subjectAltNames*, e.g.

subjectAltNames=IP:192.168.1.20

Config:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "192.168.1.20" {
  # Ensure the Pi-hole Block Page knows that this is not a blocked domain
  setenv.add-environment = ("fqdn" => "true")

  # Enable the SSL engine with a LE cert, only for this specific host
  $SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    ssl.engine = "enable"
    ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/Pihole-Home-Lan/private/Pihole-Home-Lan.key-crt.pem"
#    ssl.ca-file =  "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/Pihole-Home-Lan/public/Pihole-Home-Lan-fullchain.pem"
    ssl.ca-file =  "/etc/lighttpd/ssl/Pihole-Home-Lan/public/Home-Lan.crt.pem"
    ssl.honor-cipher-order = "enable"
    ssl.cipher-list = "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH"
    ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"
    ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"
    # client side authentification
    ssl.verifyclient.activate = "enable"
    ssl.verifyclient.enforce = "enable"
    ssl.verifyclient.depth = "10"
    ssl.verifyclient.username = "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN"
##    ssl.verifyclient.username = "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_emailAddress"
        }

  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  $HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
      url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
  }
}
```

Line from `/var/log/lighttpd/access.log` when accessing by raw address `192.168.1.20`:

```
1551209819|192.168.1.20|GET / HTTP/1.1|401|351
```

The browser shows 401 Not authorized.  Is it failing SSL or is there another problem?

Comment: Likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894290

Comment: HTTP 401 Not Authorized is a different problem.  It means "Not Authorized" and originates from the not-so-subtly-named mod_auth, which is different from mod_openssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" { ... }` (or `$SERVER["socket"] == "192.168.1.20:443" { ... }`) belongs at the top level in the config.  It is a mistake to put `$SERVER["socket"]` inside other lighttpd config conditions, i.e. it a mistake to put inside `$HTTP["host"] == "192.168.1.20" { ... }`

TLS is negotiated at the beginning of the socket connection, before the HTTP request is received over an encrypted TLS channel.  Since HTTP request `Host` header has not been received when TLS is negotiated, it is *invalid* to put `$SERVER["socket"]` inside any other condition, such as `$HTTP["host"]`